# Hard Drive became "Unknown - not initialized"

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, hardware-failure

System: Windows 10 machine, latest patch. Western Digital Blue Label 4TB - WD40EZRZ, made in 2015. 
Issue: Today, out of the blue I encountered a hard crash and restart my machine. When it rebooted - an error message: "Desktop folder (which is stored on e:) drive can't be found. When I opened File Explorer, the e: drive was gone. 
Looking into disk management, I see the following:
[image]

I opened my pc and changed out the SATA cable. The machine booted up and the disk appeared to be recognized and working fine. However, in 30 minutes or so, I got errors from some of mine programs installed on e: and the disk is once again "unknown".
Why did the disk for a little bit after I changed the cables?
Is this a sign of the disk failing so I should just buy a new one and try to salvage the data?

Comment: “Why did the disk for a little bit after I changed the cables?” - The drive clearly has seen better days, flaky behavior is typical with drives that are starting to fail, or are in a borderline state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The disk is giving clear signs of failing. Back it up while you can and then replace it.

You might consider replacing it with an SSD drive as SSDs have become more reliable than hard drives.

However, do replace it quickly